# DateTime casting works for CSV field "If Statement" logic, but not when used in second "If Statement"

Tags: powershell, csv, datetime

I am working on automating tests a DumpSec report that runs a few logical tests and displays the solution. The DumpSec is a CSV file that I use ConvertFrom-Csv and then pull dates out of each user's field. However, I need to cast the date as DateTime so that I can compare multiple DateTime fields together properly.

Casting date time works and returns the correct answers on the first "If statement" but doesn't work on the second or third "if statements" even though I'm using the same casted variable DateTime as the first.

The error I'm getting is "Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.""
$PasswordExpiresDateFormat = [datetime]::ParseExact($person.P

```
Function AutomateCSVFileFunction($DumpSecFilePath)
{
    #Variable to store the path of the passed file path
    $ImportedFile = Get-Content -LiteralPath $DumpSecFilePath | Select-Object -skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv
    
    #Variables for dates to do the correct math
    $ThirtyDays = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
    $SixMonthsAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)

    $Message = "How often does the organizations user's change their password? (Enter number of days): "
    $Title = "Organization's Password Age Limit"
    $PasswordAgeLimitDays = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($Message, $Title)
    
    #Arrays for information to be stored
    $DisabledAccounts = @()
    $LastLogonAccounts = @()
    $NeverExpireAccounts = @()
    $AccountsWherePasswordsNotRequired = @()
    $PasswordLastChangedGreaterThanAgeLimit = @()
    
    
    #For each loop to check disabled accounts greater than 6 months, 30 days inactive, accounts without an expiration date, accounts where passwords do not expire, and 
    foreach ($person in $ImportedFile)
    {
        $LastLogonDateFormat       = [datetime]::ParseExact(($person.LastLogonTime).trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", $null)
        $PasswordLastSetDateFormat = [datetime]::ParseExact($person.PswdLastSetTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", $null)
        $PasswordExpiresDateFormat = [datetime]::ParseExact($person.PswdExpiresTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", $null)

        #If statement checking each row for a disabled account greater than 6 months
        if ((($LastLogonDateFormat -lt $SixMonthsAgo) -and ($person.AcctDisabled -contains "Yes")) -or ($LastLogonDateFormat -contains "Never"))
        {
            #Add persons info to array
            $DisabledAccounts += $person
        }
        
        #If statement checking to see enabled accounts who haven't logged on in more than 30 days
        if (($LastLogonDateFormat -gt $ThirtyDays) -and ($person.AcctDisabled -like "No"))
        {
            #Add persons info to array
            $LastLogonAccounts += $person
        }
}
```

I've tried casting using only [DateTime]$VariableName, but that doesn't work either. Using the .Trim() method doesn't work either.

Comment: Just to clarify, the issue is with your `datetime` parsing as indicated in your `$PasswordExpiresDateFormat` variable. Can you show us the format (*value*) of the current output of `$person.LastLogonTime`, `$person.PswdLastSetTime`, and `$person.PswdExpiresTime`?

Comment: The last three values (because it's a loop) end up being:

11/24/2021 10:58:00 AM
11/16/2021 3:21:00 PM
10/23/2014 3:13:00 PM

Comment: That's the issue. You're string formats are not able to parse them properly with those given values. It should really be: `"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"`.

Comment: I changed the [datetime]::ParseExact($person.LastLogonTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", $null) to match what you said, but I'm still getting the same error

Also, I gave the wrong answer to $person.LastLogonTime.

The stored value looks like this 4/22/2022 6:10, so the value for $PasswordExpirationDate is 10/23/2014 3:13:00 PM and $person.LastLogonTime is 6/5/2022 9:53

Comment: I'm a bit confused since it's not clear what the issue is now. `[datetime]::ParseExact('11/24/2021 10:58:00 AM', "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", $null)` will give you an object of type `datetime`. Are you saying not all dates in your csv follow the same format?

Comment: That is correct. The dates in the CSV follow the format of 6/5/2022 9:53


I assumed since they were in a CSV, I would need to convert them from a String to a DateTime variable in order to use logical operators with them

Comment: So, it ends up being [datetime]::ParseExact('6/5/2022 9:53', "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", $null)

And using [datetime]::ParseExact('6/5/2022 9:53', "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm", $null) does not work either

Comment: The error you posted points to `$PasswordExpiresDateFormat`, and not your conditional statements: `"Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."" $PasswordExpiresDateFormat = [datetime]`. That being said, you'd have to give it a proper string format for whatever value is in `$person.PswdExpiresTime`.